# virtualenvwrapper error: could not found /usr/local/bin/virtualenv in your path

Tags: python, docker

I pull the **centos7** in docker, then i install the virtualenvwrapper

```
pip3 install virtualenvwrapper
```

config .bashrc

```
export WORKON_HOME=~/.virtualenvs
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

when i want to create a virtualenv, i got an error:

```
bash: command not found
ERROR:could not found /usr/local/bin/virtualenv in your path
```

i almost tried every method online, but it still doesnt work, did i miss something?
or the problem with **docker**??

Comment: try to add path to your virtualenv:
https://pythonspeed.com/articles/activate-virtualenv-dockerfile/

Comment: You don’t need virtual environments in Docker; the Docker image provides the same level of isolation.  Just `pip3 install` things into the “system” Python in the image.  (Also remember that many common Docker paths don’t run a `.bashrc` file and many common images don’t include GNU bash at all; writing things into a `.bashrc` file often isn’t productive.)

Comment: thx, i just realized the way i use docker was wrong.